# How to pass information from one controller to another via view rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a reservation project and after login I want to pass the current user information from the Sessions Controller to a Reservations Controller via a home page. How can I do that? I have been following Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial for the login. Here's what I have tried in the create section of the Sessions Controller

```
render home_path :local_variables[:id => user_id]
```

and in the home_path(users#home)

```
<%= link_to new_reservation_path(:user_id => :id) %>
```

but it shows me an undefined method error. My Reservation model has a user_id column.I am confused regarding this matter. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
render home_path :local_variables[:id => user_id]
```

Seems weird to me to pass locals that way (don't even know if it's possible, never seen locals used outside of rendering views/partials).

I think the best way is to redirect instead and set the user in the sessions once they have been logged in successfully, so in your login action:

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email]) # or however you are finding the person trying to login

session[:user] = user
redirect_to home_path
```

then in `users#home`

```
@user = session[:user]
```

and finally, in the view:

```
<%= link_to new_reservation_path(:user_id => @user.id) %>
```

**EDIT**

Actually, probably not a good idea to store an object in the session, instead of

```
 session[:user] = user
```

You could try:

```
 session[:user_id] = user.id
```

and then to find the user:

```
@user = User.find(session[:user_id])
```

If you still get an undefined error then it's probably because the user is nil (unless the `User` model actually has no `id` attribute, which would be strange) so there might be an issue with the login part, it's hard to say without knowing what that looks like.

If you need the logged in user on every page, you could abstract the functionality out into the application controller:

```
before_filter :check_user

def check_user
  @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

Then, you can use the `@user` instance variable anywhere in your app.

Comment: It's still not working. Shows undefined method 'id' error

Comment: Thanks for the solution @martincarlin87, I did it by the first method in your edit and now I can use the user information in my other controller